# How can we use screen cast or screen mirroring, phone display to TV connection in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-futurebuilder, flutter-devtools

I see the multiple dependencies of mirroring or cast flutter_video_cast but it's not working to connect tv and screen cast device. I use a deperecated dependencies but it doesn't work so how i can solve it and do screen cast in flutter

I expecting for the solution of screen cast or connect device in TV in flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried but not possible in Flutter. You have to write native code, then it is possible.
Android :- [Android Code](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android)
iOS :- [iOS Code](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-ios)